# Syntax error parsing <expression unary '-'>

Tags: opa

[This code snippet](http://pastebin.com/FAaX7rRV) which is an attempt to extend "hello_chat" in Opa book, is raising weird syntax errors as below:

```
[bahman@bleda Peyk]$ opa main.opa
In main.opa [24:2-24:2 | global chars=600-600]
Syntax error at line 24, column 2
The error may be in the following citation, usually in the red part (starting at ⚐) or just before:
<<(
  net = Network.cloud("PEYK")
  room_name = Dom.get_value(#room)
  server_channel = "{room_name}__SERVER"
  Network.add(room_name, net)
  ⚐Network.add(server_channel, net)

  user = String.to_lower(Dom.get_value(#user))
  do notify_room_join(server_channel, user)

>>
Hint: expected "" or "%" or "&" or ")" or "*" or "," or "->" or "/" or "/*" or "//" or ":" or "<" or "<-" or "=" or "?" or "@" or "|" or "||" or '  ' or ' ' or '+' or '-' or '^' or <spacing> or <xhtml> 
(while parsing <expression unary '-'> starting at line 23, column 2)
Error
Syntax error
```

Perhaps I'm doing some stupid mistake but couldn't figure out the source after about 4 hours.  I'd appreciate any hint/help.  TIA,

--
Bahman

Comment: Correction: http://pastebin.com/NWMFiCqT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not forget to put **do** my_fun before your function returning void ;)

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks.  I was thinking the exact opposite: just because they return `void` they don't need `do` :-)  Just curious are these considered syntax error or semantic errors?

Comment: They are actually syntax errors. A function can only have one expression (which is it's return value) and can only be preceded by bindings (`x = ...`) and `do` expressions.